# How do I check for a JSON string value in a jS if statement?

Tags: javascript, json, metadata

I'm calling user data from Memberstack which allows data to be stored as metadata in JSON. I have the following code:

```
// Set Variables //
var initiated = "Y" <--- demonstration purposes only
var startDate = new Date();
var currentDate = new Date();
// End set variqables. //

// Check initiated state. //
MemberStack.onReady.then(async function(member) {
  var metadata = await member.getMetaData()

  if (metadata = initiated.includes("Y")) {
    runTimer();
  } else {
    var sDobj = {
      startDate: startDate,
    }
    var initY = {
      initiated: "Y"
    }
    var sDobjjson = JSON.stringify(sDobj);
    var initYjson = JSON.stringify(initY);
    member.updateMetaData(sDobj, initY)
  }

})
// End check initiated state. //
```

Most of this is working except for the initial if statement (`if (metadata = initiated.includes("Y"))`) which is currently linked to the variable `var initiated = "Y"`. What I need to do is search the data I have returned under the `metadata` string response instead of the predefined `initiated` variable value.

Here is console which correctly returns `metadata = {"initiated":"N"}` from Memberstack:

[image]

Can anybody help me to get my if statement on line 28 `if (metadata = initiated.includes("Y"))` to read the string value on line 26 `metadata = {"initiated":"N"}` instead of the predefined variable `var initiated = "Y"`?

Answer (score 0):

**Change this to**

```
 if (metadata = initiated.includes("Y")) {
     runTimer();
 }
```

**This**

```
 if (metadata.initiated === "Y") {
     runTimer();
 }
```

The issue is that you are assigning the result of the validation to metadata. Also the initiated variable will not be accessible at that line as it is not defined yet

Comment: Thanks John, this has fixed this issue, although I notice now that the `var initY = {
      initiated: "Y"
    }` doesn't write correctly, console shows the else statement passing "Y" but this doesn't override the existing "N" value from the metadata recall, any ideas?